# Windows Profile Backup Script - Access Denied for Desktop Files

Tags: powershell

I am using a script I modified slightly to backup user library files.  For some reason it can backup all libraries but fails to backup any of the Desktop files.

I've tried running this as various users and on different machines but with the same result.

This is in the latest Powershell version on Windows 10.  Perhaps the code has changed since Windows 7?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Set-StrictMode -Off

#create directories for backup if needed
$TARGETDIR1 = "c:\temp"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR1 )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR1
}

$TARGETDIR2 = "c:\temp\backup"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR2 )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR2
}

$TARGETDIR3 = "c:\temp\backup\Download"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR3 )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR3
}

$TARGETDIR4 = "c:\temp\backup\Staging"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR4 )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR4
}

#Variables, only Change here
$Destination="c:\temp\backup" #Copy the Files to this Location
$Destination="C:\temp\backup\Download"
$Staging="C:\temp\backup\Staging"
$ClearStaging=$true # When $true, Staging Dir will be cleared
$Versions="5" #How many of the last Backups you want to keep
$BackupDirs="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop", "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents", "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads", "$env:USERPROFILE\Favorites", "$env:USERPROFILE\Pictures", "$env:USERPROFILE\Videos", "$env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive", "$env:USERPROFILE\Links"#What Folders you want to backup

#commented out for now --tom
$ExcludeDirs="C:\Users\seimi\OneDrive - Seidl Michael\0-Temp\Dir1","C:\Users\seimi\OneDrive - Seidl Michael\0-Temp\Dir2" #This list of Directories will not be copied

$LogName="Log.txt" #Log Name
$LoggingLevel="3" #LoggingLevel only for Output in Powershell Window, 1=smart, 3=Heavy
$Zip=$false #Zip the Backup Destination
$Use7ZIP=$false #Make sure it is installed
$RemoveBackupDestination=$false #Remove copied files after Zip, only if $Zip is true
$UseStaging=$true #only if you use ZIP, than we copy file to Staging, zip it and copy the ZIP to destination, like Staging, and to save NetworkBandwith



#Send Mail Settings
# $SendEmail = $false                    # = $true if you want to enable send report to e-mail (SMTP send)
# $EmailTo   = 'test@domain.com'              #user@domain.something (for multiple users use "User01 &lt;user01@example.com&gt;" ,"User02 &lt;user02@example.com&gt;" )
# $EmailFrom = 'from@domain.com'   #matthew@domain 
# $EmailSMTP = 'smtp.domain.com' #smtp server adress, DNS hostname.


#STOP-no changes from here
#STOP-no changes from here
#Settings - do not change anything from here

$ExcludeString=""
#[string[]]$excludedArray = $ExcludeDirs -split "," 
foreach ($Entry in $ExcludeDirs)
{
    $Temp="^"+$Entry.Replace("\","\\")
    $ExcludeString+=$Temp+"|"
}
$ExcludeString=$ExcludeString.Substring(0,$ExcludeString.Length-1)
#$ExcludeString
[RegEx]$exclude = $ExcludeString

if ($UseStaging -and $Zip)
{
    #Logging "INFO" "Use Temp Backup Dir"
    $Backupdir=$Staging +"\Backup-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd)+"-"+(Get-Random -Maximum 100000)+"\"
}
else
{
    #Logging "INFO" "Use orig Backup Dir"
    $Backupdir=$Destination +"\Backup-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd)+"-"+(Get-Random -Maximum 100000)+"\"
}



#$BackupdirTemp=$Temp +"\Backup-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd)+"-"+(Get-Random -Maximum 100000)+"\"
$Log=$Backupdir+$LogName
$Log
$Items=0
$Count=0
$ErrorCount=0
$StartDate=Get-Date #-format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss

#FUNCTION
#Logging
Function Logging ($State, $Message) {
    $Datum=Get-Date -format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Log)) {
        New-Item -Path $Log -ItemType File | Out-Null
    }
    $Text="$Datum - $State"+":"+" $Message"

    if ($LoggingLevel -eq "1" -and $Message -notmatch "was copied") {Write-Host $Text}
    elseif ($LoggingLevel -eq "3") {Write-Host $Text}

    add-Content -Path $Log -Value $Text

}


#Create Backupdir
Function Create-Backupdir {
    New-Item -Path $Backupdir -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    sleep -Seconds 5
    Logging "INFO" "Create Backupdir $Backupdir"
}

#Delete Backupdir
Function Delete-Backupdir {
    $Folder=Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending:$false | Select-Object -First 1

    Logging "INFO" "Remove Dir: $Folder"

    $Folder.FullName | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 
}


#Delete Zip
Function Delete-Zip {
    $Zip=Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Archive" -and $_.Extension -eq ".zip"} |  Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending:$false |  Select-Object -First 1

    Logging "INFO" "Remove Zip: $Zip"

    $Zip.FullName | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 
}

#Check if Backupdirs and Destination is available
function Check-Dir {
    Logging "INFO" "Check if BackupDir and Destination exists"
    if (!(Test-Path $BackupDirs)) {
        return $false
        Logging "Error" "$BackupDirs does not exist"
    }
    if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
        return $false
        Logging "Error" "$Destination does not exist"
    }
}

#Save all the Files
# note - if the folders are empty that are being copied you will see errors
#     this shouldn't affect the backup --Tom
Function Make-Backup {
    Logging "INFO" "Started the Backup"
    $Files=@()
    $SumMB=0
    $SumItems=0
    $SumCount=0
    $colItems=0
    Logging "INFO" "Count all files and create the Top Level Directories"
    }
    foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs) {
        $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h"} | Measure-Object -property length -sum) 
        $Items=0
        $FilesCount += Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h"}  
        Copy-Item -Path $Backup -Destination $Backupdir -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $SumMB+=$colItems.Sum.ToString()
        $SumItems+=$colItems.Count


    $TotalMB="{0:N2}" -f ($SumMB / 1MB) + " MB of Files"
    Logging "INFO" "There are $SumItems Files with  $TotalMB to copy"

    foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs) {
        $Index=$Backup.LastIndexOf("\")
        $SplitBackup=$Backup.substring(0,$Index)
        $Files = Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse  | select * | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h" -and $_.fullname -notmatch $exclude} | select fullname #$_.mode -notmatch "h" -and 

        foreach ($File in $Files) {
            $restpath = $file.fullname.replace($SplitBackup,"")
            try {
                Copy-Item  $file.fullname $($Backupdir+$restpath) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Out-Null
                Logging "INFO" "$file was copied"
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorCount++
                Logging "ERROR" "$file returned an error an was not copied"
            }
            $Items += (Get-item $file.fullname).Length
            $status = "Copy file {0} of {1} and copied {3} MB of {4} MB: {2}" -f $count,$SumItems,$file.Name,("{0:N2}" -f ($Items / 1MB)).ToString(),("{0:N2}" -f ($SumMB / 1MB)).ToString()
            $Index=[array]::IndexOf($BackupDirs,$Backup)+1
            $Text="Copy data Location {0} of {1}" -f $Index ,$BackupDirs.Count
            Write-Progress -Activity $Text $status -PercentComplete ($Items / $SumMB*100)  
            if ($File.Attributes -ne "Directory") {$count++}
        }
    }
    $SumCount+=$Count
    $SumTotalMB="{0:N2}" -f ($Items / 1MB) + " MB of Files"
    Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
    Logging "INFO" "Copied $SumCount files with $SumTotalMB"
    Logging "INFO" "$ErrorCount Files could not be copied"


    # Send e-mail with reports as attachments
    if ($SendEmail -eq $true) {
        $EmailSubject = "Backup Email $(get-date -format MM.yyyy)"
        $EmailBody = "Backup Script $(get-date -format MM.yyyy) (last Month).`nYours sincerely `Matthew - SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR"
        Logging "INFO" "Sending e-mail to $EmailTo from $EmailFrom (SMTPServer = $EmailSMTP) "
        ### the attachment is $log 
        Send-MailMessage -To $EmailTo -From $EmailFrom -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -SmtpServer $EmailSMTP -attachment $Log 
    }
}


#create Backup Dir



Create-Backupdir
Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
Logging "INFO" "Start the Script"

#Check if Backupdir needs to be cleaned and create Backupdir
$Count=(Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}).count
Logging "INFO" "Check if there are more than $Versions Directories in the Backupdir"

if ($count -gt $Versions) 
{

    Delete-Backupdir
}


$CountZip=(Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Archive" -and $_.Extension -eq ".zip"}).count
Logging "INFO" "Check if there are more than $Versions Zip in the Backupdir"

if ($CountZip -gt $Versions) {

    Delete-Zip 

}

#Check if all Dir are existing and do the Backup
$CheckDir=Check-Dir

if ($CheckDir -eq $false) {
    Logging "ERROR" "One of the Directory are not available, Script has stopped"
} else {
    Make-Backup

    $Enddate=Get-Date #-format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss
    $span = $EndDate - $StartDate
    $Minutes=$span.Minutes
    $Seconds=$Span.Seconds

    Logging "INFO" "Backupduration $Minutes Minutes and $Seconds Seconds"
    Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
    Logging "INFO" "----------------------" 

    if ($Zip)
    {
        Logging "INFO" "Compress the Backup Destination"

        if ($Use7ZIP)
        {
            Logging "INFO" "Use 7ZIP"
            if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {Logging "WARNING" "7Zip not found"} 
            set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 
            #sz a -t7z "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"    

            if ($UseStaging -and $Zip)
            {
                $Zip=$Staging+("\"+$Backupdir.Replace($Staging,'').Replace('\','')+".zip")
                sz a -t7z $Zip $Backupdir

                Logging "INFO" "Move Zip to Destination"
                Move-Item -Path $Zip -Destination $Destination

                if ($ClearStaging)
                {
                Logging "INFO" "Clear Staging"
                Get-ChildItem -Path $Staging -Recurse -Force | remove-item -Confirm:$false -Recurse
                }

            }
            else
            {
                sz a -t7z ($Destination+("\"+$Backupdir.Replace($Destination,'').Replace('\','')+".zip")) $Backupdir
            }

        }
        else
        {
        Logging "INFO" "Use Powershell Compress-Archive"
        Compress-Archive -Path $Backupdir -DestinationPath ($Destination+("\"+$Backupdir.Replace($Destination,'').Replace('\','')+".zip")) -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force

        }






        If ($RemoveBackupDestination)
        {
            Logging "INFO" "Backupduration $Minutes Minutes and $Seconds Seconds"

            #Remove-Item -Path $BackupDir -Force -Recurse 
            get-childitem -Path $BackupDir -recurse -Force  | remove-item -Confirm:$false -Recurse
            get-item -Path $BackupDir   | remove-item -Confirm:$false -Recurse
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Press any key to close ..."

$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

The output of the log file shows the failure here:

03.05.2019-15:01:04 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Microsoft Edge.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:01:04 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Microsoft Teams.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:01:04 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\PRMS Multi-Session.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:01:04 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\PRMS.lnk} returned an error an was not copied

Here is the output Powershell shows

```
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\desktop.ini} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED Logos & Documents.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED VPN - Shortcut.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED_DigitalNET (J) - Shortcut.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED_Sales (S) - Shortcut.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Slack.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED (U) - Shortcut.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - ERROR: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Visual Studio 2019.lnk} returned an error an was not copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - INFO: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Documents\ConnectWiseControl} was copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - INFO: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Documents\OneNote Notebooks} was copied
03.05.2019-15:36:07 - INFO: @{FullName=C:\Users\REDACTED\Documents\Visual Studio 2019} was copied
```

Comment: Far too much code dumped into the post, with an unclear problem description. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, and a more clear description of the problem than *fails to backup*. What *specifically* does *fails* mean? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error message? How can we reproduce the issue in as few lines of code as possible?

Comment: Do the logs indicate what happened?

Comment: You need to add logging to your catch to include the error message.

Comment: Copy-Item should be quoting paths in case there are spaces by the way. Like: Copy-Item  "$file.fullname" "$($Backupdir+$restpath)" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Out-Null

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are providing us the errors YOU are generating. I would like to see the actual exception's message ($_.Exception.Message) https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell

Comment: The curly brackets in function `Make-Backup` are way off.. and why are you repeating the loop `foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs)` inside an already existing identical loop? Next, you are calling `Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse -File` 3 times and on top of that also a `(Get-item $file.fullname).Length` where there is no need for that since `$file` at that point is already a FileInfo object.